# Batch file to switch mapped disk locations

Tags: windows-7, networking, script, remapping

I have to switch my mapped disk because I work on two servers and don't want to change paths stored in files I modify.

Generally both locations are mapped as P: in my company.
I've just wonder how to do something like that. Can I get your help?

I've got two net use:

```
NET USE P: /d
NET USE L: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
NET USE P: \\SEXXXXX\Projekt\
```

I run script to map as letter P:

1. if there is no mapped drive with P: script do it
   let say first one

   ```
   NET USE P: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
   ```
2. if there is already drive mapped as P: script sets actual network use as letter L: and second  sets as P: 
   and when I  run this script again it changes locations for drive mapped L and P, as in it just switches them.

I use two simple batch scripts now which look like above, but I know it is possible to use some conditions to make it works better.

It is not important for me if it will be bat script or vbs or whatever I just want to do it with run one icon.

**EDIT:**
I've tried your variations and maybe I wasn't clear enough.
Both locations (servers) are available everytime but I have to switch between them. Once I working on my local server and once on foreign server. But both are mapped as P: (for every user) so I need to do switch (depends of what project I am working now).
I can assume priority as you suggest (but there is no big matter if I will be able to switch it with again run script).
Anyway thanks for your effort.

I run script and then:

case 1a: I've got mapped disks as below

```
P: \\SEXXXXX\Projekt\ and L: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
```

when script is done - it just switch them to:

```
L: \\SEXXXXX\Projekt\ and P: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
```

case 1b: (I run script again)
so I've got at beginning:

```
L: \\SEXXXXX\Projekt\ and P: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
```

after I run it again it will return to begin

```
P: \\SEXXXXX\Projekt\ and L: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
```

case 2: (I haven't got mapped P: drive) then
script do mapping

```
P: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach.

It is clear that if you only have one network share available you want it to be mapped as `P:`
Now you need to decide on priority. Which drive do you map to `P:` when both network shares are available?
Lets assume you decide that `\\SEXXXXX\Projekt\` gets priority over `\\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment`

Then simply use:

```
NET USE P: /DELETE
NET USE L: /DELETE
NET USE P: \\SEXXXXX\Projekt\ && NET USE L: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment || NET USE P: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
```

The key here is the use of [conditional execution](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php) with `&&` and `||`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exist` to check if a drive letter exists:

```
if exist P: (
    echo Drive P exists 
    NET USE P: /d
    NET USE L: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
    NET USE P: \\SEXXXXX\Projekt\
) else (
    echo Drive P does not exist
    NET USE P: \\PLKRKXXXX.XXX.XX\Assignment
)
```